# Zend Framework - utf8 on localhost okay - utf8 on webserver fails

Tags: php, mysql, forms, zend-framework, utf-8

After searching for hours for a solution I give up. Here is my problem.
My database at localhost is `utf8_general_ci`, in my application.ini I wrote

```
resources.db.params.charset = utf8
```

Everything is fine and works.

But at the webserver the characters appears like Ã¼ or Ã¶.
I commented resources.db.params = utf8 in and out. If it is out, the characters everywhere are fine but not in any forms (label or values). If it is on every character appears like this. The same story / no effect with

```
$form->setAttrib('accept-charset', 'UTF-8');
```

I also tried

```
resources.db.params.driver_options = "SET NAMES utf8".
```

without success.

PHP version localhost:5.3.8 - MySql 5.0.8
PHP Version webserver:5.2.6 - MySql 5.0.51

Comment: Are you sure the database on your server use the utf8_general_ci collation?

Comment: Yes, the whole database, every table and every table coloumn

Comment: Also, do you send a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`-header and/or include a `<meta charset="utf-8">`-tag in your `<head>`-tag?

Comment: cool. I'll convert my comments into a proper answer.

Comment: And - of course - in bootstrap.php: $view->setEncoding('UTF-8')
Everything with no effect yet! It does not work :(((

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this is the solution, but in order to use UTF-8 in MySQL, I set the db param like this:

```
resources.db.params.charset = utf8
```

Have you tried this?

[EDIT]

You might also want to make sure the view (and thus, the form) also uses the correct encoding:

```
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

Or, if you instantiate the view manually in bootstrap:

```
$view->setEncoding("UTF-8");
```

This should make the form accept the same encoding, since it uses the view's default.

Comment: I did. When I commented this line out, than everything exept the form elements is fine.

Comment: So it's the form input that's not using UTF-8, not the database, am I correct?

Comment: When I comment resources.db.params.charset = utf8 out - yes. (With and without this line $form->setAttrib('accept-charset', 'UTF-8'); )

Comment: And the mangled characters, do they appear mangled when echoed out via your app or in phpMyAdmin as well?

Comment: Wow, another effect. By echo on locahost, there are these black ?-Signs, on webserver its fine?! In phpmyadmin all charcters are fine. (Thanks for triing helping me.)

Comment: Ah, so it's just printed out with wrong encoding, but the form & db are fine :). Check your HTML then and make sure the charset is set correctly. Check what charset your browser is picking up maybe...

Comment: Please be aware - my locahost is fine at all exept this last test (that fails). The webserver made the problem - exept this last test (that was good)

Comment: Of course, I'm not suggesting your configuration is wrong. I cannot check the site, obviously, but I suspect it's an issue with the HTML output encoding rather than the db config or the data input via the form. I might be wrong of course, but that's where the trail seems to lead.

Comment: But I use the same browser on localhost and webserver with different results? Do you have any other idea what else to configure.

Comment: Due to limited data available, not really :/

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your database is correctly configured to utilize the utf8_general_ci-collation, the problem is not so much in the database as it is a matter of telling the browser how to properly decode the HTML-response from the server.

There are two ways you can tell the browser how to decode the response:

1. Include the character encoding in the `Content-Type`-header. It will then look something like this:
   `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

   or similarly for another content type.

   `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`
2. Include a `<meta charset="utf-8">` as the first tag in your `<head>`-tag. It is important to place this tag as one of the first tags. At least before any tag containing text that needs to be displayed, such as `<title>`.

Comment: I did like this:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de-de" lang="de-de" >
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

You think it is a browser problem: But why are some character shown right and all form elements are shown wrong, if I Comment this line out: resources.db.params.charset = utf8?
Really don't understand